# Domain setting using ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, dns

I am planning to have a web application.

To do so, I studied about ruby and ruby on rails. I am using linux server from amazon clouding system.

I bought a domain from godday, and I put the IP address on DNS setting. When I run 'rails s' command, I can connect to the wep page through port 3000 in such a way that domain.com:3000. However, I cannot directly connect to domain.com. How can I my domain works without port 3000?

And Do I have to run 'rails s' every time to make the wep page work? Actually I tried to use 'rails s &' to make it run in background. But it fails. How can I make the server run even though I am not connected to the linux server?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah that time I had no idea about the concept of webserver. Now I'm using nginx. It works very good. Thank you for checking again! By the way, this is my web app link: miamimarkets.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually you use `rails s` just in development. there are quite a few ruby web servers you can choose from for your production environment: [puma](http://puma.io), [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) or [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) to name a few.

of course all of them have their own tutorials how to set them up. for starters, i'd go with with passenger because it's integrated with nginx and apache and easily set up.

Comment: I installed 'puma' and run the server with puma, but the same problem. I can connect to 'www.domain.com:3000', but cannot connect to 'www.domain.com'

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a port, if you don't see the port it can be either 80 (http) or 443 (https).

```
rails server -p 80
```

On linux you have to be root to bind to port less than 1000, so just append **sudo** in front.

Comment: I use AWS and default port is 22. I ran both 'rails s -p 22' and 'sudo rails s -p 22'. However, for the first one, it shows error and the server doesn't run, and second one, it says 'sudo rails not found'...? what am I supposed to do?